# How to fix the tooltip's position when scroll the X-axis of charts in the Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, highcharts

I have a line chart that customized the tooltip and put the x-axis scrollbar using the Highcharts library
It is running well, however, once I move the scrollbar, tooltip's position isn't scrolled.
The source code of the tooltip and the scrollbar is following as:

```
var tooltip = {
     headerFormat: '<span style="font-size: 14px; color: {point.color}">{series.name}</span><span 
                           style="font-size: 20px; color: {point.color}">({point.y})</span><br/>',
     pointFormatter: function (point) {
         return tooltipValue[this.x];

     },
    footerFormat: "",
 }
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'spline',
        scrollablePlotArea: {
            minWidth: 1000,
        },
    }
    });
```

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug which is already reported on Highcharts issue channel. See:

https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/12682

If you need a workaround please ask the core developers in the comment under the above link.